# how to add custom button on product

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I have created Custom Button using following Code at `themes/package/woocommerce/single-product/add-to-cart/simple.php`

```
<?php 
    if($_product->getCustom_button()){ //yes or no button
?>
    <button type="button" title="<?php echo $_product->getCustom_button_name() ;?>" class="btn btn-default" onclick="window.open('<?php echo $_product->getCustom_button_url() ;?>')"><span><span><i class="icon-desktop"></i><?php echo $_product->getCustom_button_name() ;?></span></span></button>
<?php } ?>
```

but this code is not work properly.
i want custom button work with product attributes. 
[image]

Comment: Please explain yourself little-bit more, share what is your intention to do and what issue you are facing right now.

Comment: when i have add above mention code simple.php show my page is blank and product image, footer and addtocard button and custom not showing an

Comment: What is `$_product`, what does `getCustom_button()` do?

Comment: i have use same code in magento site this code work perfectly and custom_button is attribute id

Answer (score 1):

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button','cmk_additional_button');
function cmk_additional_button() {
    echo '<button type="submit" class="button alt">Change me please</button>';
}
```

add this code in your Child theme functions.php

Try this code

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to add anything like button, text using this below code

```
function my_custom_content(){
    // get_the_ID() is product ID
    // echo anything you want
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'my_custom_content' );
```

Comment: this code is not work

Comment: May be you did not use it in correct way, this is the best solution to add custom content like button on the section you are looking for

Comment: i want custom button in singal product page and i have past your  code at themes/package/woocommerce/single-product/add-to-cart/simple.php